# How to fix: webform_calculate doesn't read values in fields that have been 'set to' by conditionals

Tags: webform-civicrm

Drupal7, Civi5.12
I've used webform conditionals to 'set to' values for fields. Now I want to run calculations on those fields using webform_calculate,

But webform_calculate won't recognise the 'set to' values.
Any ideas?

Comment: Davy, does this work with pure webform components - ie is it really webform_civicrm that is the problem?

Comment: I’m 99% sure we got this working; Make sure your set to fields are of type Number and that all fields involved in the calculation are on the same page. We recently worked on a patch for webform_calculator module  that allows you to have fields across multiple pages but have not had a chance to PR that yet.

Comment: @KarinG-SemperIT Can you please confirm whether this functionality is working as of now?  I'm using CiviCRM 5.27.5, Webform 7.x-4.23, and Webform Calculator 7.x-2.0-beta1.  If I set an amount in a number field based on a conditional, then attempt to use the participant fee field as a formula (so I can calculate reg amount-discount) the participant fee does not get set.